# ArrayFormula Holiday Planner

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

In Google Sheets, I am trying to make a holiday planner where my team can put in the start and end dates of their holidays in a booking sheet and then “Yes” or “No” is populated in the corresponding cell in the team planner. The booking sheet looks like this:
Booking Sheet (https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1r7d.png)

The team planner looks like this:
Team Planner (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrFOC.png)

I am using the array formula below in the cells in the team planner but it isn't working:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND($A$2:$A="Alex", $D$2:$D="Holiday", F$1>=$B$2:$B, $C$2:$C>=F$1), "Yes", "No"))

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `AND` functions don't array with `ARRAYFORMULA`, but you can get the same affect by rewriting your syntax with an `*`, like this:

**Before:**

```
AND($A$2:$A="Alex", $D$2:$D="Holiday", F$1>=$B$2:$B, $C$2:$C>=F$1)
```

**After:**

```
($A$2:$A="Alex") * ($D$2:$D="Holiday") * (F$1>=$B$2:$B) * ($C$2:$C>=F$1)
```

`AND` can be replaced by using `*`'s

`OR` can be replaced by using `+`'s

I'm having trouble understanding the use of your formula though, it seems like you may be trying to return "yes" if that person is scheduled to be out during the month of `F1:I1`, but the formula you're posing would only return yes if the data in the same row matched. For example `A2`=Alex and `E2`=Fabio so those lines wouldn't match in your array.

Are you trying to build a filter that will return yes if Alex has requested time off during the month in F1:I1?

Comment: Hi Alex! Yes you are right, perhaps this formula isn’t returning what I need. I am indeed trying to build a filter to see if Alex has booked time off during a period. However instead of a month is is a specific date as the holiday planner has a cell for each date rather than each month. Do you know a better way of doing this?